# Strange behavior in ASP.NET when parsing the route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Given this method in a Controller

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

A request like this is successful! 
http://localhost:53351/api/values/**abc**

Why?

IMHO, this should throw as a **Bad Request** because the id is not a number (it's "abc"). Instead, I'm getting a 0 (zero) as the `id` parameter.

**MOREOVER =>**

A very similar problem also happens in methods like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id, [FromQuery]QueryObject queryObj)
{
    return "value";
}

public class QueryObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

In a request like this
http://localhost:53351/api/values/1?String=hello&Number=**abc**
the object that is parsed and put as `queryObj` will come with its number property set to 0 (zero).

This makes invalid data go through the pipe! Can we avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the type of the parameter like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
```

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference)

**Second Part**

You need to add `[FromQuery]` attribute to the model properties

```
public class QueryObject
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "String")]
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice! but how do we get it in a "query object"? I have just edited the OP to reflect the problem (under the MOREOVER title).

Comment: Thanks! But how could we add restrictions to the QueryObjects? like forcing the Number to accept only integers. In the attribute you put there is only the name (for mapping purposes, I guess). What I need is to avoid getting a 0 in Number if I put "&Number=abc" in the querystring. I would like to get a Bad Request or something to indicate to the consumer that the query isn't well-formatted.